How to properly generate a self-signed certificate for a quic server in rust?
I tried using rcgen, but when I try to conenct to http3 with my browser, firefox says "rx_record_too_long". Other browsers just say "invalid ssl certificate".

Did you register the certificate in your store?

Also, OpenSSL can generate certificates.

I tried using a certificate from a local CA which I added to my store, instead. That error doesn't seem to be related to the certificate being untrusted though. If I let it use a new self-signed certificate, I'm expecting it to just warn me that the ssl certificate is untrusted.

I want to auto generate self-signed ssl certificates, so that users don't HAVE to set up proper https, if they just want to use it locally, with the warnings.

Ideally, I'd have insecure http for local network use be an option (it's also useful for development), but http3 can't do that.
